# Drools cannot resolve a global variable

Tags: drools

i'm trying to add String items to a global variable $items. But i get an error "$items cannot be resolved"

Below is snippet of my drl rule. What am i missing?

[code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGLkE.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

**First**: in drl file

```
global java.util.HashSet items

rule "rule 1"
    when
    then
        items.add("Item 1");
        System.err.println(items);
end
```

**Second**: in java file

```java
KieSession kieSession = ...
kieSession.setGlobal("items",new HashSet<>());
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you. But now my new problem is I only get 1 item added to the Set even if i have more matching rules. Seems the add() is only called once. I'm expecting about 4 items from my test

Comment: I think you might need to check your rules, my local test is fine.

[see this picture](https://gitee.com/huan1993/images/blob/master/blog/drools-global.jpg)